# Why does the hist() function not have area one

Tags: r, histogram, area

When using `hist()` in R and setting `freq=FALSE` I should get a densities. However, I do not. I get other numbers than when it just shows the count. I still need to normalize.

For example:

```
> h = hist(c(1,2,1,3,1,4,5,4,5,8,2,4,1,7,6,10,7,4,3,7,3,5), freq=FALSE)
> h$density
  0.13636364 0.15909091 0.09090909 0.09090909 0.02272727
> sum(h$density)
  [1] 0.5
> h$density/sum(h$density)
  [1] 0.27272727 0.31818182 0.18181818 0.18181818 0.0454545
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you examine the rest of the histogram output, you will notice that the bars have length 2:

```
$breaks
[1]  0  2  4  6  8 10
```

Hence you should multiple the `sum(h$density)` by 2 to get the area equal to one. You can see this clearly if you look at the histogram.

[image]

Comment: And to get the widths use `diff(h$breaks)`

Answer (score 1):

The area of the histogram is, in fact, `1.0`. What you're not taking into account is that every bar is two units wide:

```
> h$breaks
[1]  0  2  4  6  8 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(h$density*(h$breaks[-1] - h$breaks[-length(h$breaks)]))

[1] 1
```

Comment: Or just use `sum(h$density*diff(h$breaks))`

Comment: Thanks! You learn something every day. Great to know cause I do this quite often.

Answer (score 1):

The density is not the same as the probability. The density for a histogram is the height of the bar. The probability is the area of the bar. You need to multiply the height times with width to get the area. Try

```
x <- c(1,2,1,3,1,4,5,4,5,8,2,4,1,7,6,10,7,4,3,7,3,5)
hh <- hist(x, probability = TRUE)
sum(diff(hh$breaks) * hh$density)
# [1] 1
```

The works because `breaks` contains the start/end points for each of the bins. So by taking the difference between each value, you get the total width of the bin. You can also `with()` to more easily grab both of those values.

```
x <- c(1,2,1,3,1,4,5,4,5,8,2,4,1,7,6,10,7,4,3,7,3,5)
with(hist(x, probability = TRUE), sum(diff(breaks) * density))
# [1] 1
```